# android live wallpaper to home launcher

Tags: android, layout, wallpaper, launcher

I have a problem. I am making a "home launcher" and I set the background with this code:

```
sfondo = peekWallpaper();
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(sfondo);
```

If the background is static, OK. But if the background is animated it shows a static background. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you use an image wallpaper like .png, .jpg, or .gif. ImageWallpaper only draws when there are changes on surface like changing event, offset change event. 
It doesn't draw every second like a live wallpaper which quite draws every milliseconds.
Even you set image wallpaper with animated image like .gif as ImageWallpaper, it only draws  when specific events happens.